# How to open a link (<a href="#">Link</a> ) in html opened in Chrome into Internet Explore?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am currently creating a website and one URL link should be opened in Internet explore when it is clicked. For example, Link is html tag that was opened in Gooogle chrome, and when I clicked on it, that should be opened in Internet Explore. Please, help me to solve this problem. It is quite important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no solution to this. The `<a href>` element tells the Operating System that it has to open a application that can deal with a url. This is like the `mailto:` element that opens your email application if you click on it. The problem is, that the user can choose what application he wants to use when clicking on an http link. You can notice this when you open an unknown filetype on windows and windows asks you wich application you want to use. This is similar to the http link wich will always be opened by de default browser, unless the user tells the OS he wants to use another default browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer dear! Besides <a href> is there any way to open something in Internet exploree, for example: button, any others

Comment: @ArslonbekKulmatov No, the link or button actually delivers the url, which has a `http` in front. This `http` is to tell the Operating System that a browser should be used, wich is the default browser, in your case chrome. There really is no option to turn this behaviour off as this is intended from the Operating System...